# Can SaveInstanceState be called before onCreate() was finished?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-lifecycle

I'm sorry if it's a dumb question, I just have a weird behavior in production that can be explained if somehow `onSaveInstanceState` was called but `onCreate` was not (or at least didn't finish executing).

Here is the code:

```
private LaunchedFrom launchedFrom = null; 

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  // some members initialization

  if (savedInstanceState == null) {
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    launchedFrom = handleIntentAction(intent);
  } else {
    // Restoring saved state.
  launchedFrom = LaunchedFrom.fromEvent(savedInstanceState.getString(BundleParams.KEY_LAUNCHED_FROM));
  }
}

protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
  super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
  outState.putString(BundleParams.KEY_LAUNCHED_FROM, launchedFrom.getEvent());
}

private LaunchedFrom handleIntentAction(Intent intent) {
  LaunchedFrom launchedFrom = LaunchedFrom.MAIN;
  if (intent != null) {
    // some logic to override launchedFrom
  }
  return launchedFrom;
}
```

I am sometimes (quite rarely) getting an NPE in `onSaveInstanceState` having a null launchedFrom.. 
Thanks for your help..

Comment: Can you elborate by code what you are doing in onSaveInstanceState and onCreate and onRestoreInstanceSate realated to state of activity

Comment: I guess it'll have something to do with garbage collecting.. Does this `NPE` is raised after you put your app in the background for a while, for example?

Comment: We have an app with ~ten thousand DAUs. This is happening maybe once or twice a day. I don't know what they do.. We can live with it, but it still intrigues me.

Comment: I've kinda stumbled upon a similar issue where one of the objects I'm trying to access in onSaveInstanceState is null and giving an NPE, and that object is initialized in onCreate. I can't think of any situation where onSaveInstanceState is called before onCreate, perhaps when the app crashes?

Comment: @rafaelc Can you elaborate more on the garbaze collection here? Your theory sounds right since crashlytics does mentions that most of these crashes happen when device is in background.

Answer (score -3):

As Per [Documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html)

> **void onRestoreInstanceState (Bundle savedInstanceState)**
>
> This method is called between onStart() and onPostCreate(Bundle).
>
> **void onSaveInstanceState (Bundle outState)**
>
> If called, this method will occur before onStop(). There are no
>   guarantees about whether it will occur before or after onPause().

I hope this helps. Though It is not defined as to when onSaveInstanceState() may be called.

Comment: At what conclusion does this quote of the documentation get?

Comment: read the paragraph above Configuration Changes for onSaveInstanceState and https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onSaveInstanceState(android.os.Bundle), read this link for onRestoreInstanceState https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onRestoreInstanceState(android.os.Bundle).

Comment: This doesn't even try to answer the question :-(

Comment: @DavidWasser before the above question was edited he asked "if somehow onSaveInstanceState was called but onCreate was not (or at least didn't finish executing)" i answered this accordingly.